# Taking binary tree as input(recursively)

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion

I am supposed to take input of a binary tree recursively as :

10 true 20 true 40 false false true 50 false false true 30 true 60 false false true 73 false false

so the tree created should be:-

```
        10
    20      30 
 40   50  60   73
```

I have created a function which cannot create this tree, whats wrong in the code?

```
node* takeInput() {
    int data;
    string a;

    cin>>data>>a;
    node*n = NULL;

    if(a=="true") {
        n = new node(data);
        n->left = takeInput();
        n->right = takeInput();
    }
    if(a=="false") {
       return NULL;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Explain your input!

Comment: @RajeevSingh If a node has lchild or rchild then its "true" else "false".

Comment: @RajeevSingh so for example '40 false false' means it has no leftchild and rightchild.          "30 true 60 false false true 73 false false" means 30 has left child 60 and 60 has no childs(60 false false) and 30 has right child also "true 73" where 73 has no childs(73 false false).

Comment: The tree is made as - Current node-> then make Left Subtree -> Then make Right Subtree. And recursive function based on the above pattern can be used to make the Tree.

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS yes. so.. whats the problem with the code?

Comment: I'lll Try to make it.

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS Okay! would help a lot.

Comment: What exactly do parentheses have to do with whatever you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the input as inorder tree traversal...

1. First Take input for the root node.
2. Then take input for left subtree if exists.
3. Then take input for right subtree if exists.

Code:

```
void takeInput(Node* &node) {
    string left, right;
    int data;
    cin >> data; // input for root node
    node = new Node(data);

    cin >> left;
    if(left == "true") {
        takeInput(node->left); // taking input for left subtree
    }

    cin >> right;
    if(right == "true") {
        takeInput(node->right); // taking input for right subtree
    }
}

Node* InputBinaryTree() {
    Node *root;
    takeInput(root);
    return root;
}
```